# "Terms of the sequence" vs. "Terms of the series"

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm reading Stewart Calculus, 8th edition, p.748, where I found "The number s is the sum of the series. [...] By adding sufficiently many terms of the series we can get as close as we like to the number s."

I'm confused because by definition in the same book, it says a series is the sum of a list of numbers. If the series itself is the sum, is saying "the sum of the series." the same as saying "the sum of the sum."? Or does "the sum of the series" actually mean "the sum of the numbers in the sequence"?

And when referring to "terms of the series", is the author referring to "terms of the sequence"?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If I write the series $1 + \frac12 + \frac14 + \frac18 + \cdots + \frac1{2^n} + \cdots$, then it has value $2$.  The number $2$ is not the series but it _is_ the "sum" or "value" of the series.  It is unfortunate that we also use the word "sum" to denote both the expression $1+2$ and its value $3$, because many people don't like allowing the word "sum" to talk about the series itself but only its value.  In this sense, "the sum of the series" shouldn't be replaced by "the sum of the sum"

Comment: I disagree slightly with @BrianMoehring. Brian's series and the sum `0+2` both have value 2; we can also say that the *terms* `0` and `2` sum to 2 or (collectively) has the sum 2; we don't really say that `0+2` (or any sum/series) has the sum 2, but when I hear that I will read it as saying that the sum/series has value 2 (after all, the sum of a single number is technically just itself). Finally, "terms of the series" and "terms of the sequence" are synonymous.

Comment: Thank you @Brian Moehring. So the sum is the value, or the result of adding the terms of the series, while the series is the expression, such as of 1+2+3...